# SharePoint Hosted app Custom newform

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I need to add a custom form (new, view and display forms) in a SharePoint Hosted app.  I did follow these two articles [article1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-custom-new-edit-display-form-to-list-using-sharepoint-ho/)  and [article2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wilsonreddygajarla/2014/12/13/sharepoint-list-newform-customization-in-sharepoint-hosted-app/).

Steps so far

- Created a SharePoint App project
- Added a custom list (Employee) to the app
- Added a custom new form and set the deployment type of the aspx to element file
- Added the following line in the list schema.xml file

  '<'Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewEmployee.aspx" Path="NewEmployee.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main"Template="NewEmployee.aspx"/>'

  When I change the original form tag to the one shown above as suggested by the solution successfully builds but fails during installation.

The error in the Output window is as below

App installation encountered the following errors:
  05/04/2017 00:12:02

```
@"Error 1
        CorrelationId: 0c2af6ff-a1f6-4706-8b49-7a1797dd3fab
        ErrorDetail: There was a problem with activating the app web definition.
        ErrorType: App
        ErrorTypeName: App Related
        ExceptionMessage: <nativehr>0x80131600</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
        Source: AppWeb
        SourceName: App Web Deployment
Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Failed to install app for SharePoint
```

.